# Odd $k$-cycle counts in graph with adjacency matrix $A$ is leading term in $\operatorname{tr} A^k$?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, graph-theory

In a recent paper of Neeman, Radin, and Sadun, [Moderate Deviations in Cycle Count](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.08249), in the first line of section 7.3 they wrote $\tau_k(A)=\frac{\operatorname{tr}A^k}{n^k}+O(\frac 1n)$, but I don't know why this is true. Here $A$ is an adjacency matrix of some graph $G$ of $n$ vertices,

$$\tau_k(A)=\frac{1}{{n\choose k}}\#\{\text{injective }\phi:[k]\mapsto V(G):(\phi(i),\phi(i+1))\in E(G),\forall i\}$$

is the $k$-cycle homomorphism density in graph $G$, where $k$ is odd.

My main problem is why the number of closed walks with repeated edges is negligible? I think $k$ being odd plays a significant role here since for even $k$ we can have $\operatorname{tr}[A^k]\gg n^k\tau_k(A)$ by looking at sparse Erdős–Rényi graphs.

Comment: Is it possible, that the $\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})$ comes not from the number of walks with repeated edges being negligible, but from the random graph being less likely to allow repeated edges? When $n$ grows, the chance of two edges in $V(G)$ being between the same vertices becomes small.

Comment: @Tardis: so you mean the probability of having repeated edges is even rarer than the moderate deviatoin event, thus we can ignore it?

Comment: No sorry, my mistake. I misread how $m$ grows with $n$ and thought we would have ever less edges for ever more vertices. My argument doesn't work.